# Toggling animation, or adding a class?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm fiddling around creating a little slide-out menu. I'm having problems because I now realise `.animate()` is not toggle-able.

So I planned to create a CSS class and use `.cssToggle()` instead, but this does not animate.

What is the correct way to make something like this toggleable, in order to make the menu close again using the same icon?

```
$( ".menu span" ).click(function() {
 $( ".menu" ).animate({
     left:0
  }, 500, function() {
  })
})
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk1j6c4k/1/).

Comment: you can create custom animator using setInterval(). you need to increment left of div within interval tick up to maximum and vise visa.

Comment: here is my updated version of [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jk1j6c4k/6/) you can customize speed ofanimation with increment/decrement values and timer interval

Answer (score 0):

You can check with '.css( "left" )' function the left position of your element. When its "0" you will set the value of variable for "xx" pixels and when it's "xx" then u will set the variable for "0" value.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? If you had, you'd realise it does nothing towards what I'm trying to achieve, and actually breaks moreso than what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the menu when its gone to the left and is not visible and when you click on it again check if its visible or not and then do the action accordingly:

```
$( ".menu span" ).click(function() {

var menu = $('.menu');

if($(menu).is(':visible')){
 $(menu).animate({
     left:0
  }, 500, function() {
      $(menu).hide();
  })
}else{


$(menu).show(function(){
   $(menu).animate({left:200},500);

})


});
```

I have not tested the code but i guess the logic should work..

Answer (score 0):

How about using **animate** like below to make it toggle

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jk1j6c4k/4/)**

```
$( ".menu span" ).click(function() {
   var th = $('.menu');
        if ($(th).css('left') !== '0px') {
            $(th).animate({
                "left": "0"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $(th).animate({
                "left": "-95%"
            }, 500);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself in the end by using a CSS3 transition. I used `.toggleClass()` instead, and added `transition:1s;` to both CSS styles that affect the placement of the menu div. This means when clicked the class is added or removed, and transitions mean it animates properly.

```
$( ".menu span" ).click(function() {
    $( ".menu" ).toggleClass('open');
});

.menu{position:absolute;left:-95%;height:100%;transition: 1s;}
.open{left:0; transition: 1s;}
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jk1j6c4k/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target audience I would not rely on javaScript but css for simple animations like this. Just toggle a class on your menu, like so:

```
$( ".menu span" ).click(function() {
   $( ".menu" ).toggleClass('open');
})
```

And than do all the magic in css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #bada55;
}
.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  /* Move the menu off screen, adjust if you want that menu bar to be visible at all times */
  transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.menu span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.menu.open {
  transform: translate(0, 0); /* Move the menu to the desired place */
}
.menu.open span {
  /* Reposition the toggle element */
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

See an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/ck/pen/KDsFC).

I'm using `transform: translate(-100%, 0);` and `transform: translate(-100%, 0);` because it performs better, but you can use `position` as well to get support for older browsers (they will not get the transition though).

For information about Browser support see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).